# Google Invisible ReCaptcha with Master Pages not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the Google Invisible ReCaptcha to work properly in our ASP.NET/C# web app. with Master Pages and Panels.  Here is the top of the web page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Login.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoginRetail.aspx.cs"     Inherits="OnlineSpecialOrders.Forms.LoginRetail" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSubmit() {
        window.location.href = '~/MainPage.aspx';
    }
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/styleSO.css" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderPageHeading" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderBody" runat="server">
<div id="divMain" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" align="center" runat="server">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="generalcontent">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlRetail" runat="server" Width="960px" Visible="true" DefaultButton="loginButton">
                    <div id="Div7" style="border: medium ridge #863C18; width:575px; height:400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto" align="center">
                        ...
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="THISISOURNONSECRETSITEKEY" data-callback="onSubmit" data-size="invisible"></div>
                        <div style="margin-left: 15px" class="floatL">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="loginButton" Text="Login" CssClass="button brown bigrounded" Width="150px" Height="30px" OnClick="onlineSpecialOrderRetailLogin_Authenticate" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                        </div>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
private bool ValidateRecaptcha()
    {
        string captcha_secret_key = "THISISOURSECRETKEY";
        string url = @"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        string postData = $"secret={captcha_secret_key}&response={Request["grecaptcha-execute"]}&remoteip={Request.UserHostAddress}";

        try {
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            writer.Write(postData);
            writer.Close();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            CaptchaResponse cResponse = jss.Deserialize<CaptchaResponse>(responseData);

            return cResponse.success;
        }
        catch (WebException) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    class CaptchaResponse
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
    }
```

When we call the ValidateRecaptcha() method, it is returning false.  Also, if I put a breakpoint on the onSubmit() function, it never goes there, not does it ever display the Recaptcha pictures.  I've verified that the two keys are correct for what we have registered.  I do get the "Protected by reCAPTCHA" message at the bottom right of the web page.  I have a reference to the Recaptcha.dll in References.  I'm hoping there is something obvious and simple that we're overlooking.  We are currently using the old 1.0 ReCaptcha on this website just fine.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show an example implementation I've used in the past for this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over some of my own WebForms recaptcha code, it looks like you're sending over the wrong request variable, `Request["grecaptcha-execute"]`, as the response instead of `Request["g-recaptcha-response"]`.

I'm also not certain that attaching the secret as form data is the right way to go (although it may very well work) when the implementations I've seen would have instead set the requests' url to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={captcha_secret_key}&response={Request["g-recaptcha-response"]}&remoteip={Request.UserHostAddress}`

Here's a more fully worked example:

```
var secretKey = "IAMASECRETKEY";
var captchaResponse = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, captchaResponse));
using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    if (responseStream != null)
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            CaptchaResponse data = serializer.Deserialize<CaptchaResponse>(json);
            return data.Success;
        }
```

Comment: I have put the above mentioned code in a method that returns a bool.  Right now the above code is always returning FALSE, and maybe that's O.K.  I have a method that does some validation, then calls the above method.  I guess I'm not understanding how, after the above code returns FALSE, to call the g-recaptcha code in the DIV statement?